# Excel column chart absolute value to percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any configuration in excel that i use absolute values, and the excel shows percentage values on the y axis?

(I need to this automatically, without any formula or etc.. just chart configuration)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regular chart, insert a **Pivot Chart** (Insert > PivotChart > PivotChart). The fields panel will appear on the right. Drag your values into the "values" field and your labels into the "rows" field. Click on the item in the values field, then "Value field Settings...". Click on the tab "Show values as..." then select "% of grand total".

More info here (section "Show values as"): https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576